# When I construct a second new Polynomial(linked list) class, the first one takes the second one's values

Tags: java, list, constructor, linked-list

```
package polynomial;

/**
 *
 * @author Steven
 */

public class Polynomial
{
private float data;
protected static Polynomial head;
private Polynomial link;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */    
public Polynomial(float[] data)
{
    head = null;

    if(data.length == 1)
        head = insertAtFront(head, data[0]);

    for(int i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(head);
        head = insertAtFront(head, data[i]);
    }
}

public Polynomial(float data, Polynomial link)
{
    this.link = link;
    this.data = data;
}

public static Polynomial add(Polynomial p, Polynomial p2)
{
    if(p.length() > p2.length())
    {
        while(p.length() != p2.length())
            {
                insertAtFront(p2, 0);
            }

        for(Polynomial poly = p; poly != null && p2 != null; poly = poly.link)
        {
            p2.data = (p2.data + poly.data);
            p2 = p2.link;
        }
    }
    else if(p2.length() > p.length())
    {
        while(p2.length() != p.length())
            {
                insertAtFront(p, 0);
            }

        for(Polynomial poly = p; poly != null && p2 != null; poly = poly.link)
        {
            p2.data = (p2.data + poly.data);
            p2 = p2.link;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(Polynomial poly = p; poly != null && p2 != null; poly = poly.link)
        {
            p2.data = (p2.data + poly.data);
            p2 = p2.link;
        }
    }
    return p2.head;
}

public float evaluate(float x)
{
    int i = head.length()-1;
    float y = 0;
    for(Polynomial poly = head; poly != null; poly = poly.link)
    {
        if(poly.link == null)
            y += poly.data;
        else
            y += (poly.data * (float)(Math.pow(x, i)));
        i -= 1;
    }
    return y;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    int i = 1;
    String polyString = "blank";
    for(Polynomial poly = head; poly != null; poly = poly.link)
    {
        if(polyString.equalsIgnoreCase("blank"))
        {
            if(poly.data != 0)
                    polyString = poly.data + "x^" + (poly.length()-i) + " + ";
            else if(poly.data == 1)
                polyString = "x^" + (poly.length()-i) + " + ";
            else
                polyString = poly.data + "x^" + (poly.length()-i) + " + ";
        }
        else
        {
            if(poly.link == null)
            {
                if(poly.data != 0)
                    polyString = polyString + poly.data;
                else if(poly.data == 1)
                    polyString = polyString + "x";
                else
                    polyString = polyString + poly.data + "x^" + (poly.length()-i);
            }
            else
            {
                if(poly.data != 0)
                    polyString = polyString + poly.data + "x^" + (poly.length()-i) + " + ";
                else if(poly.data == 1)
                    polyString = polyString + "x^" + (poly.length()-i) + " + ";
                else
                    ;
            }
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return polyString;
}

public int length()
{
    int answer = 0;

    for(Polynomial poly = head; poly != null; poly = poly.link)
    {
        answer++;
    }
    return answer;
}

private static Polynomial insertAtFront(Polynomial head, float data)
{
    return new Polynomial(data, head);
}

}
```

I have a second class that is just a program to run these methods, and when I create a new Polynomial, and run associated methods, everything appears to run successfully. After I create a new Polynomial, the first Polynomial takes the second one's values. I don't understand 1. where the first-created polynomial's values are going and 2. why it's doing this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected static Polynomial head;
```

your `head` is declared as `static` - thus there is only one copy of it for all classes! Once your second `Polynomial` is created, it overrides the head of the first one.

You probably want it to be an instance variable and not a class variable.

Though, doing it will also have its own problems of infinite recursive constructor invokation. To overcome it, you might want to have a different class that holds a `Polynomial head`  as an instance variable, and initialized it only once per list.